# NullPointerException Student class organizer android

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception

So I'm making a simple class manager for students and I can't figure this out. From the main activity there is a button to add a class, which takes you to the add class activity which has an add student button which takes you to the add student activity. When I save the student, it works just fine by returning you to the add class activity and adding the student name to the roster listview. But for some reason when I save the class, I get a nullPointerException on return to the main activity. If anybody has any ideas, I'd really appreciate the help.

Here's the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView classList;
Button addClass;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterClass;
ArrayList<Class> currClasses = new ArrayList<Class>();
ArrayList<String> currClassNames = new ArrayList<String>();
ClassesSingleton myClasses;
int REQUEST_CODE_ADD = 318;
int REQUEST_CODE_EDIT = 319;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    classList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.classList);
    final Context context = this;
    adapterClass = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_list_item, R.id.label, currClassNames);

    classList.setAdapter(adapterClass);

    addClass = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.addClass);

    classList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> arg0, View view, int position, long id){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShowClass.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EDIT);
        }
    });

    addClass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddClass.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_ADD);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ADD){
        Class newClass = new Class();
        if(data.hasExtra("className")){
            newClass.setName(data.getExtras().getString("name"));
        }
        if(data.hasExtra("number")){
            newClass.setNumber(data.getExtras().getInt("number"));
        }
        if(data.hasExtra("students")){
            ArrayList<Student> s = data.getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("students");
            newClass.setStudents(s);
        }
        if(data.hasExtra("names")){
            ArrayList<String> sn = data.getExtras().getStringArrayList("names");
            newClass.setStudentNames(sn);
        }

        myClasses = ClassesSingleton.getInstance();
        updateClassList(newClass, newClass.getName());
        myClasses.setClassArray(currClasses);
        myClasses.setClassNames(currClassNames);
    }

    //else if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_EDIT){

    //}
}

public void updateClassList(Class n, String s){

    adapterClass = null;
    currClasses.add(n);
    currClassNames.add(s);
    adapterClass = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_list_item, R.id.label, currClassNames);
    classList.setAdapter(adapterClass);
    adapterClass.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Here's the add class activity:

```
public class AddClass extends Activity{

Button addStudent, saveClass, cancelClass;
EditText className, classNumber;
ListView studentList;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapterStudent;
ArrayList<Student> currStudents = new ArrayList<Student>();
ArrayList<String> studNames = new ArrayList<String>();
int REQUEST_CODE_ADDSTU = 317;
int REQUEST_CODE_EDSTU = 316;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.new_class);

    addStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addStudent);
    saveClass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmClassAdd);
    cancelClass = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelClass);
    className = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newClassName);
    classNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newClassNumber);
    studentList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newStudentList);
    adapterStudent = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_list_item, R.id.label, studNames);

    studentList.setAdapter(adapterStudent);

    studentList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView <?> arg0, View view, int position, long id){
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(AddClass.this, EditStudent.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent2, REQUEST_CODE_EDSTU);
        }
    });

    addStudent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0){
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(AddClass.this, AddStudent.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent2, REQUEST_CODE_ADDSTU);
        }
    });

    saveClass.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            Intent data = new Intent();
            int numData = 0;
            if(className.getText().toString().matches("") != true && classNumber.getText().toString().matches("") != true && currStudents.isEmpty() != true && studNames.isEmpty() != true){
                String nameData = className.getText().toString();
                String numStr = classNumber.getText().toString();
                ArrayList<Student> students = currStudents;
                ArrayList<String> studentNames = studNames;

                boolean intTrue = true;
                try{
                    numData = Integer.parseInt(numStr);
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    Toast.makeText(AddClass.this, "Please be sure to enter a numberic value in the number field.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    intTrue = false;
                }

                if(intTrue){
                    data.putExtra("className", nameData);
                    data.putExtra("number", numData);
                    data.putStringArrayListExtra("names", studentNames);
                    data.putParcelableArrayListExtra("students", students);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(AddClass.this, "Don't leave your class name, number field, or student roster blank!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

//onActivityResult callback
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_ADDSTU){
        Student newStudent = new Student();
        if(data.hasExtra("name")){
            newStudent.setName(data.getExtras().getString("name"));
        }
        if(data.hasExtra("id")){
            newStudent.setId(data.getExtras().getInt("id"));
        }

        updateStudentList(newStudent, newStudent.getName());
    }
}

public void updateStudentList(Student s, String n){
    adapterStudent = null;
    currStudents.add(s);
    studNames.add(n);
    adapterStudent = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_list_item, R.id.label, studNames);
    studentList.setAdapter(adapterStudent);
    adapterStudent.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

}
```

Here's the add student activity:

```
public class AddStudent extends Activity{

EditText studentName, studentId;
Button saveStudent, cancelStudent;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_student);

    studentName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newStudentName);
    studentId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.newStudentId);
    saveStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmStudentAdd);
    cancelStudent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelStudent);

    saveStudent.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0){
            Intent data = new Intent();
            int idData = 0;

            if(studentName.getText().toString().matches("") != true && studentId.getText().toString().matches("") != true){
                String nameData = studentName.getText().toString();
                String idStr = studentId.getText().toString();

                boolean intTrue = true;
                try{
                    idData = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    Toast.makeText(AddStudent.this, "Please be sure to enter a numeric value in the ID field.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    intTrue = false;
                }

                if(intTrue){
                    data.putExtra("name", nameData);
                    data.putExtra("id", idData);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(AddStudent.this, "Don't leave your student name or ID field blank!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.congelassign2, PID: 1664
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14785)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14785)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14785)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14785)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14785)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1985)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1742)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5582)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Which method throw exception.Exception stack trace is unclear

Comment: At which line thrown error??

Comment: Seems some problem with your adapter.. please post the complete code

Answer (score 0):

Looking at exception seems like 'ListView classList' is not initialising befor being used in onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

Its showing error because you are trying to show the custom layout in your `ArrayAdapter` class. To use the Custom layout in `ArrayAdapter` you need to create separate custom adapter class which extends `ArrayAdapter` class and inflate a layout into that adapter class.

The way which you are trying to inflate a layout is wrong that is why you are getting error `at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)` As its going to refer android layout to bind the data into listview.

Also your both ArrayList `ArrayList<String> currClassNames = new ArrayList<String>();` and `ArrayList<String> studNames = new ArrayList<String>();` are null.